# PyCharm: Deleting/Modifying returned arguments (refactoring)

Tags: refactoring, pycharm

I am trying to remove some of the returned arguments of a function called at multiple places in my working pipeline with PyCharm. PyCharm allows me to do this only for input arguments (via Refactoring -> Change Signature) but I am struggling to find a way to automatically do the same for returned arguments.

So far, my only solution is to find the usages of the function and to delete by hand the output parameters at every single call...

I will be happy if anyone can help.

I am using PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2